# Switching between views of a CardLayout

Tags: java, user-interface, frame, cardlayout

I am trying to use a `CardLayout` to switch between views for a game I am trying to program, but I am having some troubles doing so. Here is what I got:

EDIT: update the code to what I currently have

```
panelCont = new JPanel();
JPanel panelFirst = new JPanel();
JPanel panelSecond = new JPanel();
JButton buttonOne = new JButton("Start");
final CardLayout c1 = new CardLayout();

panelCont.setLayout(c1);

panelFirst.add(buttonOne);
panelSecond.add(this);

panelCont.add(panelFirst, "1");
panelCont.add(panelSecond, "2");
c1.show(panelCont, "1");

buttonOne.addActionListener(new
    ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            c1.show(panelCont, "2");
        }
    });
```

I want to use the button to switch between the view with the game, but when I run it, the screen is just blank when I press the button. Thanks.

Comment: You should name each card with a unique name; `cards.add(card2);`

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I changed up my code and now have it to where I run the program I get a screen with a button that says "Start" which is what I want, but then when I hit start, the CardLayout switches to the second card but instead of it running the game, its just a blank screen. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you need to "start" the game in some way! Like get the fame loop running?

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Yes, I do. I am just not sure where I would put that in. The second panel I have is supposed to contain the game. I am going to update my code here to show you what I currently have.

Comment: Probably after card.next

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Okay, here's the new code. How would the next method start the game? The way I have it now switches to the next view which is what I want, but when I switch the the next view, the game is not running. I need to invoke the `.go()` method somewhere, but I'm not sure where to call it in here since I am just switching views.